# Paytm CheckSumServiceHelper maven dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, checksum, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm with my SpringBoot project. But I am not getting a proper jar for the Paytm CheckSumServiceHelper class. I have tried to integrate the MAVEN dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paytm/pgplussdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paytm</groupId>
    <artifactId>pgplussdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but I'm getting Missing artifact com.paytm:pgplussdk:jar:1.3.3 in pom.xml

I have checked multiple links, the package looks like "com.paytm.pg.merchant", but I'm not getting the accurate jar.

Comment: did you try this [jar](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Google_App_Engine_Kit) reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763945/not-able-to-import-com-paytm-merchant-checksumservicehelper-when-running-beanshe

Comment: Yes, but no luck with that as well

Comment: package `com.paytm.pg.merchant` is available in this Paytm checksum utility jar, for java [7](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java/tree/master/Java%20Kit%201.7) and [8](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java/tree/master/Java%20Kit%201.8). reference: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/checksum/

Comment: This is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PaytmCheckSum.jar [Paytm_JAVA_Checksum](https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_JAVA_Checksum) .

But the class name is changed from CheckSumServiceHelper to PaytmChecksum
Eg.

1. `PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(parameters, paytmDetails.getMerchantKey());`
2. `PaytmChecksum.verifySignature(parameters,paytmDetails.getMerchantKey(),paytmChecksum);`

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).